# Send data to php (form method=post) and then send it back to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I just need guidance on whether I am still on the right path or not, I am currently learning Javascript.

So I have a dynamic form (the number of inputs fields differs according to couple of conditions) that I need to reuse its data later on, so once the form is submitted, its data is sent to saveAnswers.php

HTML

```html
<form action=saveAnswers.php method=POST>..</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $answers = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key_post => $value_post)
    {
        array_push($answers, $value_post); 
    }
    echo json_encode($answers);
?>
```

Now my question is how to send this data ($answers) from PHP to javascript, My php background is none to existence, thats why I am not using raw php files. I understood that I need to do it through AJAX. How to call the function in Javascript if I write it there? 
As the moment I click on submit answers, I go the saveAnswers.php 
Any guidelines or tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery for that:

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.submit(function() {
    // do POST ajax request
    $.post($form.attr('action'), data: $form.serialize(), function(data) {
        // data will be your $answers array from php
    }, 'json');
    return false; // prevent submitting of the form
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible try this example
 we have the following variable in PHP:

```
$name = 'Bob Marley';
```

And we want to pass it to a JavaScript variable called name

```
echo '<script>'; echo 'var name = ' . json_encode($name) . ';'; echo '</script>';
```